# Hi,Why this 'tile price of certain sqf area' function does not work?

Tags: python, function, calculator

Sorry, I am new here. I think I did not explain enough. I am trying to make a tile price calculator. So you enter the height and width of a place and pick price of tile you want and I calculate approximate tile cost. My class function runs and asks for width and height but not for the price.

```
class Tile_calc:

    def __init__(self, height = 1, width = 1):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

        self.height = int(input("What is height?"))
        self.width = int(input("What is width?"))

    def price(self, pr = 1):
        self.pr = pr
        self.pr = int(input("please enter squarefeet price of a tile"))

        return self.widht*self.height*self.pr
```

After I run it asks for height and width than gives error below.

```
What is height?10
What is width?30
<__main__.Tile_calc at 0x4f14088>
```

Comment: This is not an error. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Ideally, post the main method of your code, where you parse the input, construct your `Tile_calc` object and use it. That will help people understand how you're running the code and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please update your question with the real code you are using.

Comment: You haven't called `.price()` after instantiating the class…?!

Comment: btw self.pr = pr does nothing because you overwrite it on the next line.

Comment:  Same for `height` and `width` in `__init__`…

Comment: And you have a typo in the last line of your `price` method - you use `self.widht` instead of `self.width `

Answer (score 3):

That is not an error, it is a representation of an instance of your class. By default all you get is a string containing the class name and the id of the object instance (which is the object’s memory address in CPython). You can define your own representation of your instance:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return  f'Tile_calc(height={self.height}, width={self.width})'
```

Comment: self.height = height
self.width = width      I think I already defined them but somehow 2nd function does not ask for the price

Comment: @SametTarakçı you have to call your function to ask for the price: `Tile_calc().price()`

Comment: Thank you how can I make it under Tile_calc() alone?

Comment: then just move ` self.pr = int(input("please enter squarefeet price of a tile"))` in the constructor

Comment: How can I run all in Tile_calc()

Comment: I did, it only gives * symbol at the left and did not work

Comment: @SametTarakçı can  you open a new question with the new issue? and add all your details?